# Trying with Selenium + Excel VBA to scrape code from a site in Chrome Browser

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I need some guidance with scraping text from a website in Chrome (v 75.0.3770.142) using Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140) in Excel (2013) VBE.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-if="!ShippingDetails.isShippingCreatedOutsideSH" ng-bind="ShippingDetails.code" class="">3333333</div>
```

The portion I need to extract is the "3333333"

I'm still brand new to Selenium Type Library and have clumsily tried with this novice attempt so far:

```
Dim SHN As String
SHN = obj.FindElementByXPath("//div[@ng-if='!ShippingDetails.isShippingCreatedOutsideSH']/ng-bind[@'ShippingDetails.code']").Text
MsgBox SHN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//div[@ng-bind='ShippingDetails.code']").Text
```

Answer (score 2):

To print the text **3333333** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  - Using `.Text`:

    ```
    Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("div[ng-if$='isShippingCreatedOutsideSH'][ng-bind^='ShippingDetails']").Text
    ```
  - Using `.Attribute("innerHTML")`:

    ```
    Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("div[ng-if$='isShippingCreatedOutsideSH'][ng-bind^='ShippingDetails']").Attribute("innerHTML")
    ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  - Using `.Text`:

    ```
    Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(@ng-if, 'isShippingCreatedOutsideSH') and starts-with(@ng-bind, 'ShippingDetails')]").Text
    ```
  - Using `.Attribute("innerHTML")`:

    ```
    Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(@ng-if, 'isShippingCreatedOutsideSH') and starts-with(@ng-bind, 'ShippingDetails')]").Attribute("innerHTML")
    ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Vba selenium code to get data from Li class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027188/vba-selenium-code-to-get-data-from-li-class/49028684#49028684)